# Getting 404 error on simple WCF call hosted in IIS from jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf, http-status-code-404

This is going to sound like a very familiar post, but I'm trying to call a local-IIS hosted WCF service from a local-IIS hosted ASP.NET WebApp.  The local web app can successfully "call" the .svc file from the AJAX call below but as soon as I add the /GetData?value=2, I start getting 404 errors.

Both the WCF service and the web app are hosted on localhost in IIS7 so I shouldn't be running into any cross-domain issues.

I apologize that this same question has been asked about 100 million times and I'm just another WCF noob trying to get it to work, but any help would be greatly appreciated.  I've been Googling and trying different things for about a day now and I finally submit.

Thanks,
Jason

Here's my Service Contract:

```
namespace WcfService1
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method="GET", ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        string GetData(int value);

        [OperationContract]
        CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);

        // TODO: Add your service operations here
    }


    // Use a data contract as illustrated in the sample below to add composite types to service operations.
    [DataContract]
    public class CompositeType
    {
        bool boolValue = true;
        string stringValue = "Hello ";

        [DataMember]
        public bool BoolValue
        {
            get { return boolValue; }
            set { boolValue = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string StringValue
        {
            get { return stringValue; }
            set { stringValue = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the Service Implementation:

```
namespace WcfService1
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode=AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }

        public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
        {
            if (composite == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
            }
            if (composite.BoolValue)
            {
                composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
            }
            return composite;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the service web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="default">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="httpEndPoint">
                <webHttp />
                <!--<enableWebScript />-->
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
      <services>
          <service behaviorConfiguration="default" name="Service">
              <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="httpEndPoint"></endpoint>
              <endpoint address="mex" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" behaviorConfiguration="httpEndPoint"></endpoint>
          </service>
      </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>

 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value="Service1.svc" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Here's my AJAX call:

```
    $(document).ready(
        function()
        {
            $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "http://localhost/testservice/GetData?value=2",
//                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
//                    DataType: "jason",
                    success: function() { alert("success"); },
                    error: function(result) { alert(result.status + " " + result.statusText); }
                }
            );
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the setup for a rest service due to the webHttp tag in the config.

Instead of

```
http://localhost/testservice/GetData?value=2
```

Do

```
http://localhost/testservice/GetData/2
```